# Proof of PNT using RH

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis

Is there any proof of Prime Number Theorem that follows immediately from the Riemann Hypothesis? I know that if RH is true then $\sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) = x^{1/2 + \epsilon}$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. This in turn implies that $\sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) = o(x)$ from which PNT follows. But I am asking for a proof that follows immediately not via some long route.

Comment: It was an enormous task to prove the prime number theorem. I am not at all an expert in this , but I doubt that assuming the Riemann hypothesis allows an easy proof of this deep theorem.

Comment: RH implies no zeros on $s=1$ which implies PNT!

Comment: the question is what do you mean by immediately and what do you mean by a proof of PNT?\; As noted above, a known (but not trivial) equivalence for PNT is that zeta has no zeroes on the line $1$, so in a sense PNT is a necessary condition for RH; in that sense of course the result (RH implies PNT) is trivial by simple logic, but again it requires a whole chain of non trivial considerations to show that necessity

Comment: Can you suggest me some references which show this equivalence. The proof of prime number theorem I am familiar with, requires estimates for $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta'(s)$ which not show that $\zeta(s)$ does not vanish on the line $s = 1$ but also show that it does not vanish in a certain region to the left of $s = 1$. This in turn gets used in the Perron's formula to establish $\psi(x) = x + O(x \exp(-c (\log x)^{\alpha}))$ where $\alpha$ depends on how "big" the zero free region is. It's hard for me to fathom how this not too difficult fact of $\zeta(1 + it) \neq 0$ gives us PNT.